# twitter bootstrap - increasing the height of a form field to match button

Tags: html, forms, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm trying to make the height and font size of my search bar larger with twitter bootstrap.. such that it also works in responsive mode.

```
<div class="hero-unit center">

    <h2>Search</h2>

    <form class="form-search">
        <div class="input-append">
            <input type="text" class="span6 search-query" placeholder="Type here...">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large">
                <i class="icon-search"></i>
                Search
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

the thing is that im using btn-large class on the button but dont know if there is an equivalent way to make the search field also larger..

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is only classes for size and alignment for text input. And you cant just add btn-large since it is ignored. However, you can add inline css to the input with the exact same features as btn-large

```
style="padding: 11px 19px;font-size: 17.5px;"
```

or in a CSS class

```
input.edit-btn-large {
   padding: 11px 19px;
   font-size: 17.5px;
}

<form class="form-search">
  <div class="input-append">
     <input type="text" class="span6 search-query btn-large" placeholder="Type here..." style="padding: 11px 19px;font-size: 17.5px;">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large">
          <i class="icon-search"></i>
          Search
      </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

aligns perfectly :-)

[image]

**Update**

---

I've messed a lot around with responsive design, eg `@media all { }` and so on, but nothing seems to really work. Hovever, just remove `span6` from the class-declaration (I cannot see why this should be nessecary on the `<input>`-element anyway) and it works in all resolutions!

eg

```
input.edit-btn-large {
   font-size: 17.5px;
   padding: 11px 19px;
}
```

and

```
<input type="text" class="search-query edit-btn-large" placeholder="Type here...">
```

Comment: This works well on the main browser.. but fails when the browser is resized ... eg: on the mobile phone... assuming using bootstrap-responsive design. Thanks for your input so far though...

Comment: The same for me! It work's perfect when the browser window maximized. When I'm resizing browzer it fails. Maybe you can suggest some solution?